# Delete specific date vale from range of range dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database 'fare'. It has columns vehicle_number, date_from, date_to and fare.
There are several vehicle number entires for date range defined in date_from to date_to and its fare during that particular
date range.

```
vehicle_number  date_from    date_to       fare 
ABC123         2013-04-19   2013-04-24     $50
ABC123         2013-04-25   2013-04-29     $100
ABC123         2013-04-25   2013-04-29     $120

ABC124         2013-04-19   2013-04-21     $20
```

I want run a query suppose where 
vehicle_number-->ABC123 
for `DATE 2013-04-20 fare as -->NULL`
So that table can be displayed as

```
vehicle_number  date_from       date_to       fare 
ABC123         2013-04-19   2013-04-19     $50
ABC123         2013-04-21   2013-04-24     $50
ABC123         2013-04-25   2013-04-29     $100
ABC123         2013-04-25   2013-04-29     $120

ABC124         2013-04-19   2013-04-21     $20
```

I tried INSERT query and inserting NULL in at that date, its getting inserted NULL but not getting required output.
Also, DELETE is deleting whole row from the DB.

Query for inserting dates and fares originally:

```
INSERT INTO fare (`vehicle_number`,`date_from`, `date_to`,`fares`) VALUES ('$vehicle_number','$from','$to','$vehicle_fares')
```

Tried this query to make NULL

```
INSERT INTO fare (`vehicle_number`,`date_from`, `date_to`,`fares`) VALUES ('ABC123','2013-04-20','2013-04-20',NULL)
```

After this it shows below output:

```
vehicle_number  date_from    date_to       fare 
ABC123         2013-04-19   2013-04-24     $50
ABC123         2013-04-20   2013-04-20     
ABC123         2013-04-25   2013-04-29     $100
ABC123         2013-04-25   2013-04-29     $120

ABC124         2013-04-19   2013-04-21     $20
```

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: Hi Joce, Thanks for your response!! edited my question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to just display dates that are not 4-20. This is not an appropriate context for inserting a new record. Instead you should modify your query to simply exclude this date in the returned results:

```
SELECT * FROM fare WHERE vehicle_number = ABC123 AND date_from <> 2013-04-20 AND date_to <> 2013-04-20
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, It should display the output as per table number 2 from above(i mean it should not show that particular entry at all), as per your query it will show different output.